# nth-child based sub category hide show in multiple rows

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make some hide show items based on nth-child or count based selector.
if I click first item in first row then first item of second row should display and other items in that row should hide.   Please help for simplified code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".subrow1 .item-a a:nth-child(1)").click(function(){     
        $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(1)").show();  
         $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(2)").hide();
          $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(3)").hide();
           $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(4)").hide();
           $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(5)").hide();
           $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(6)").hide();
    });
    $(".subrow1 .item-a a:nth-child(2)").click(function(){     
        $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(2)").show();  
         $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(1)").hide();
          $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(3)").hide();
           $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(4)").hide();
           $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(5)").hide();
           $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(6)").hide();
    });

     $(".subrow1 .item-a a:nth-child(3)").click(function(){     
        $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(3)").show();  
         $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(1)").hide();
          $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(2)").hide();
           $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(4)").hide();
           $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(5)").hide();
           $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child(6)").hide();
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/244/

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/index/, https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle. Please view this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/245/ Let me know if it helps. I added an extra attribute to your buttons and wrote the following jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".subrow1 .item-a a").click(function(){  
        var show_div = $(this).attr('show');
        $('.idgroupsub').each(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $('.idgroupsub.item-'+show_div).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with the "index()" function and select with css like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".subrow1 .item-a a").click(function(){
        var index = $(this).index()+1;
        $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:nth-child("+index+")").show();
        $(".subrow2 .idgroupsub:not(:nth-child("+index+"))").hide();
    });

});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/CodeFoxx/us1nk859/